# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00900

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(
  CustID number(5,0),
  EmpID CHAR(1),
  Cust_Name varchar(20) not null,
  Cust_Address varchar(20) not null,
  Cust_City varchar(20) not null,
  Cust_State char(2) not null,
  Cust_Zipcode number(5,0) not null,
  Ship_Date date not null,
  Order_Date date not null,
  constraint ci_fk FOREIGN KEY (EmpID) references EMPLOYEES(EmpID),
  constraint ci_ck check (Ship_Date>Order_Date)
)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employees table does not exist.

or EmpId is not a primary key.

Once I did these, my copy of the create statement worked.

Comment: It does. desc employees Object Type  TABLE Object  EMPLOYEES        
Table Column Data Type Length Precision Scale Primary Key Nullable Default Comment
EMPLOYEES EMPID Char 1 -  -  1 -  -  -
  LASTNAME Varchar2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  FIRSTNAME Varchar2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  ADDRESS Varchar2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  ADDRESS1 Varchar2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  CITY Char 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  STATE Char 2 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  ZIPCODE Char 5 -  -  -  nullable -  -
  1 - 8

Comment: If I create table Employees but have empId not a primary key I get this:  <eb1>ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
State:S1000,Native:2270,Origin:[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]</eb1>      What error are you getting?

Comment: It's a primary key, see table description.

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked. Maybe data was not updated or something.

Comment: Like Daniel, I had no problems creating the table.  It's odd that you'd be getting an ORA-00900 error, because I thought that related strictly to procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Chris said it.

Change CHAR to VARCHAR2 as CHAR should never be used.  Also, number(5,0) is the same as NUMBER(5), so you can use that.

Comment: For columns with a max. length of 1 character, `CHAR(1)` is perfectly fine. When knowing that the state is always exactly 2 characters long, then there is nothing wrong with using `CHAR(2)` for that as well.

Comment: "CHAR should never be used" is an excellent example of a statement that begs for qualification. :P

Comment: Agree with client09. There's no benefit in a CHAR over a VARCHAR2. There are cases where it isn't worse than a VARCHAR2, but why have the added complication.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the Employees table exists.

Verify that the EmpID column in the Employees table is of the same datatype as in the Customers table.

Verify that the EmpID column in the Employees table is the primary key of the employee table.